# Login application not working

Tags: angularjs

This is my first application in Angular. I was not sure why it is not working.

```
    <body ng-controller="LoginController">
<div name="signIn" class="box-content">
<div class="box-top-content">

        <label>Username:</label><input type="text" ng-model="username" /></br> 
        </br> <label></label>Password:</label><input type="password" ng-model="password"></br>
        <button type="submit" ng-click="submit()">login</button>
    </div>
```

My JS is:

```
var loginApp = angular.module('loginApp', []);

loginApp.factory('authFactory',function(){

var authFactory ={};


authFactory.login = function (username,password){
     if ( username == "abc" && password=="test")
         return true;
     else
         return false;

};
return authFactory;

});

loginApp.controller('LoginController', function($scope,authFactory) {

$scope.submit= function ($scope,authFactory) {
    authFactory.login($scope.username, $scope.password).then(function (status) {

           if (status) {
                 alert("not welcome");
              }
              else {
                  alert("welcome");
              }

       }); 


};



});
```

When I click on Submit button  ,nothing happens. No error message. Whats wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the object inside of the factory:

```
loginApp.factory('authFactory',function($http){
    var authFactory ={};
    authFactory.login = //...

    return authFactory;  //Here it is
});
```

Comment: For the sake of completion and to further explain what's happening with that return, here's a great explanation of the Revealing Module Pattern:

http://carldanley.com/js-revealing-module-pattern/